# PHP, possible to call the function from within the same function without specifying function name?

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to call function within the same function without specifying the function name - e.g by using some sort of magic keyword?

Comment: sounds like a bad idea, what ever your asking.

Comment: @Dagon it sounds good for a recursion of generated functions.

Comment: @binarious If you're generating the functions, you should know their names. I've implemented half a dozen (related, code-sharing) code generators full of mutually-recursive functions in the last months, and in each code generator, I use a mapping with the name of every function to great effect.

Comment: @delnan No if they're anonymous functions.

Comment: @binarious If you need recursion, you obviously shouldn't generate anonymous functions ;) Besides, I can think of large ranges of code generation tasks that become unnecessarily hard or entirely impractical if one is bent on anonymous functions. For instance, anything that needs to call a function from multiple places :) Moreover, it's really easy and gives you a shot at useful tracebacks and more readable output - implement a trivial symbol table along with identifier generation. That's like 20 lines of trivial code w/o blanks, and I made the function names relate to the input.

Comment: This is not the right place for this debate ;). And I belive that there are usecases for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The constant `__FUNCTION__` gives you a string representation of the current function. ([src](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php))

```
function testMe() {
  print __FUNCTION__;
}

testMe(); // outputs "testMe"
```

You can then of course use this to call itself:

```
$func = __FUNCTION__;
$func();
```

Comment: Also, `__METHOD__` if you're in an OO context.

Comment: Nice! Is this callable? ie $foo = __FUNCTION__($arg);, will be trying when I get home. I agree this can be abused, yet I can also imagine using this for generic recursive functions. I imagine it could apply to some algorithms.

Comment: won't be callable directly, you have to stuff \_\_FUNCTION\_\_ into a var first. but could probably be useful if you want a recursive anonymous function ^^

Comment: @SamuelHerzog you could call it with `call_user_func(__FUNCTION__)`, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction($i)
{
     $method = __FUNCTION__;
     if ( $i > 0 )
     {
         return $method($i-1);
     }
     return $i;
}
```

simple example of recursion without knowing the functions name, will call itself for `$i`-times if `$i` is positiv.